# Automated UI tests on safari with Azure DevOps ##[error]The current operating system is not capable of running this task

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, safari

I need to automate some UI webtest with safari on Azure DevOps and was wondering if anyone knows how to do it?

i found out that the [VSBuild on azure devops does not work on macos VM's](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/11136). So are there any known solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Build task is only supported on agents running Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops

[image]

For MacOS, you could use "MS build" and "dotnet build" for the build task, and test with "dotnet test" task.

[image]